# Best convention to cancel a 'One week trial' for customers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So I got a webapp in the MEVN stack. On my webapp I offer different payment plans. One of them is 'One Week full Access' for a fixed fee. When the user orders that package, I update the property `isCustomer` in `mongodb` that is linked to the user and set it to `true`.

```
.then(() => {
    user.isCustomer = true
        user.save()
            .then(() => {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    msg: ""
                });
            })
})
```

The idea is that after a week the property should automatically update and set back to `false`, but I have no idea where to start with this. I also don't know what is the best convention to handle these type of situations. Could someone shed some light on what is best to do in these circumstances?

Comment: Instead of a simple boolean flag, set an expiration date to a week from now. Then check the current time against the expiration date when they log in.

Comment: Solid idea, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea:

- add property `user.expirationDate`

  - your access checking code would have to check the `expirationDate` upon login
  - redirect to regular subscription account page
- add property `user.accountType`

  - secondary or daemon process could reap expired accounts or expired trial

Comment: Thanks, solid solution to the problem. I think I am going with yours :).

Answer (score 1):

In video games, access to parts of the game are often granted with video game items like keys or magic spells.

You could create objects that represent various access permissions, and give those objects expiration dates.

Then create a requiresPermission function which looks for any valid membership object and returns false if it does not find a current (not expired) one.

What I like best about this approach is the ability to create granular permissions and to abstract access rules behind a single requiresPermission function.

Comment: Interesting idea! I'll look at the possibilities within my own app. Thanks for taking the time to leave an answer :).